# Limits on Salesforce Excel connector data

Tags: soql, query, excel, salesforceexcelconnector

I have configured sforce_connect.xla add-in in excel to fetch data from salesforce to excel sheet. Now for query results I am getting maximum 790 records where it should be 1000 or more as I can confirm. Can someone let me know where the limit is set in the add-in and how to overcome that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post your query for more help.

Comment: You can certainly retrieve more records than that, so as guest610 says, sounds like it is a query issue. Maybe post a screenshot of the criteria you are using?

Comment: I have no query . It's a drag and drop directly from excel to salesforce.